# Erro em `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(myTdm, c(names(termFrequency2[i])), : Repeated indices currently not allowed

Tags: r

Tenho o seguinte código em R, funcionava na versão 3.0.2, porém nas superiores apresenta o erro

> Erro em `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(myTdm, c(names(termFrequency2[i])), 
>   :    Repeated indices currently not allowed.

```
myTdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus11,control=list(wordLengths=c(3,Inf)))
et3 <- pam(myTdm, 3)
matrix.kmet <- as.matrix(met3$clustering)
termFrequency <- rowSums(as.matrix(matrix.kmet))

#faz um desses p/ cada cluster
termFrequency2 <- subset(termFrequency, termFrequency == 3)

#gero o tamanho da matriz de acordo com o tamanho do cluster
#recupera a frequencia da palavra

a <- matrix(nrow=1, ncol=2)
for(i in names(termFrequency2)) {
    b <- NULL
    z <- inspect( myTdm[c(names(termFrequency2[i])), dimnames(myTdm)$Docs] )

    b <- matrix(c(names(termFrequency2[i]), rowSums(z)), nrow=1, ncol=2)
    a <- rbind(a, b) 
}
```

Comment: O que são `myCorpus11` e `met3`?

Comment: met3 é o resultado do algoritmo kmedoids nos dados e myCorpus11 é o vetor de palavras após passarem pelo pré processamento textual.

Comment: @MarjoriKlinczak, do jeito que está o seu exemplo ele é dependente do myCorpus11 e do met3. Para conseguir reproduzir o seu problema o ideal era você postar alguns mini exemplos de objetos (myCorpus11 e met3) com a mesma estrutura que está apresentando o erro que você está vendo.

Comment: Talvez você possa tentar usar mesmo num R mais recente uma versão anterior do pacote tm. Ajudaria se você postasse o resultado de `sessionInfo()` ou alguma outra informação de diagnóstico.